# Pytorch custom loss function is not decreasing

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, autograd

Here is my custom loss function which is the mean false error loss. I've been told that topk() breaks the computational graph so I am sure the breaking happens after in the code after #get y_hat_labels comment but I am unsure about how to re-write it to not break the computational graph. Any comments are appreciated!

```
def mfe(dict_dataloader, y_hat, y, msfe=False):

            if torch.backends.mps.is_available():
                device = torch.device('mps')
            elif torch.cuda.is_available():
                device = torch.device('cuda')
            else:
                device = torch.device('cpu')

            #prepare and assign variables from the dataset
            no_of_classes = dict_dataloader['n_class']
            sample_sizes = dict_dataloader['n_per_class_train']
            positive_class_sample_size = min(sample_sizes)
            positive_class = sample_sizes.index(positive_class_sample_size)

            #get y_hat labels
            _, y_hat_labels = torch.softmax(y_hat, dim=1).topk(1, dim=1)
            y_hat_labels = y_hat_labels.squeeze().float().requires_grad_().to(device)

            #one-hot encode labels
            target_labels_oh = F.one_hot(y, no_of_classes).float().to(device)
            y_hat_labels_oh = F.one_hot(y_hat_labels.type(torch.int64), no_of_classes).float()

            #get the rows of positive condition from target tensor
            positive_class_rows = target_labels_oh[(target_labels_oh[:, positive_class]==1)].to(device)

            #get the indices of rows with real positive labels
            pos_indices = (target_labels_oh[:, positive_class]==1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]

            #get the corresponding rows in prediction tensor
            pos_rows_yhat = y_hat_labels_oh[pos_indices].to(device)

            #FNE equation
            false_negative_error = (torch.tensor(1/positive_class_sample_size, requires_grad=True))*torch.sum(torch.sum(0.5*(positive_class_rows-pos_rows_yhat)**2, dim=1))

            #FPE equation
            neg_class_indices = [index for index, value in enumerate(sample_sizes) if value != positive_class_sample_size]
            false_positive = []

            for i in neg_class_indices:
                negative_class_rows = target_labels_oh[(target_labels_oh[:, i]==1)].to(device)
                neg_indices = (target_labels_oh[:, i]==1).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
                neg_rows_yhat = y_hat_labels_oh[neg_indices].to(device)
                false_positive_error_per_class = (torch.tensor(1/sample_sizes[i], requires_grad=True))*torch.sum(torch.sum(0.5*(negative_class_rows-neg_rows_yhat)**2, dim=1))
                false_positive.append(false_positive_error_per_class)

            false_positive_error = sum(false_positive)

            false_positive_error.requires_grad_(True).to(device)
            false_negative_error.requires_grad_(True).to(device)

            #final calculation
            if msfe==False:
                loss = false_negative_error + false_positive_error
            else:
                loss = (false_negative_error)**2 + (false_positive_error**2)
            
            loss.requires_grad_(True)
            return loss.to(device)
```